# Query calculate Balance in SAP B1 hana database

Tags: hana, sapb1

Here is table i have

```
SELECT T0."TransId",
T0."Account",
T0."TransType",
SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN T0."TransType" = '15' THEN T0."Credit" END,T0."Credit")) As "Credit",
SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN T0."TransType" = '13' THEN T0."Debit" END,T0."Debit")) As "Debit",
SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN T0."TransType" = '13' THEN T0."Debit" END,T0."Debit")) - SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN T0."TransType" = '15' THEN T0."Credit" END,T0."Credit")) "Balance"
FROM JDT1 T0
WHERE T0."RefDate" BETWEEN '2022-09-01' AND '2022-09-30'
AND T0."Account" IN ('4101101','5101101')
GROUP BY T0."TransId", T0."Account",T0."TransType"
```

[image]

and the problem is, how calculate balance from field Debit & Credit

Comment: That's called a *running total*. There have been several previous questions about how to do them. Please search this site for *SQL running total*.

Comment: do you need to swap credit and debit in your subtraction?